# Binary Search Tree Problem

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

Why the search and successor and predecessor returns -1?

```
    // BST.cpp : main project file.

    #include "stdafx.h"
    #include <cstdlib>
    #include <iostream>
    #define SIZE 10
    using namespace std;

    struct Node {
        int value;
        Node *left;
        Node *right;
        Node *parent;
    };

    struct BST {
        Node *root;
    };

    void insert(int value, BST *tree) {
        Node *x = tree->root;
        Node *y = NULL;
        Node *z = (Node *) malloc(sizeof(Node));
        z->left = NULL;
        z->right = NULL;
        z->value = value;

        // Add your code here
        while (x!=NULL){
              y=x;
              if (z->value < x->value)
                 x= x->left;
              else x = x->right;
        }
        z->parent=y;
        if (y==NULL)
           tree->root=z;
        else if (z->value <y->value)
             y->left =z;
        else y->right =z;

    }

    Node *search(int key, Node *n) {
        if (n== NULL || key == n->value)
            return n;

        if (key < n->value)
            search(key, n->left);
        else
            search(key, n->right);
    }

    Node *min(Node *n) {
        if (n == NULL || n->left == NULL)
            return n;
        else
            return min(n->left);
    }

    Node *max(Node *n) {
        if (n == NULL || n->right == NULL)
            return n;
        else
            return max(n->right);
    }

    Node *successor(int value, Node *n) {
        Node *y = NULL;

        Node *x = search(value, n);

        if (x == NULL)
            return NULL;

        if (x->right != NULL)
            return min(x->right);

        y = x->parent;
        while (y != NULL && x == y->right) {
            x = y;
            y = y->parent;
        }
        return y;
    }

    Node *predecessor(int value, Node *n) {
        Node *x = search(value, n);
        Node *y = NULL;
        if (x == NULL)
            return NULL;

        if (x->left != NULL)
            return max(x->left);

        y = x->parent;
        while (y != NULL && x == y->left) {
            x = y;
            y = y->parent;
        }
        return y;
    }

    Node *remove(int value, BST *tree) {
        Node *z = search(value, tree->root);
        Node *y = NULL, *x = NULL;

        if (z == NULL) return NULL;

        if (z->left == NULL || z->right == NULL)
            y = z;
        else
            y = successor(value, z);

        if (y->left != NULL)
            x = y->left;
        else
            x = y->right;

        if (x != NULL)
            x->parent = y->parent;

        if (y->parent == NULL)
            tree->root = x;
        else if (y == y->parent->left)
            y->parent->left = x;
        else
            y->parent->right = x;

        if (y != z) {
            int tmp = z->value;
            z->value = y->value;
            y->value = tmp;
        }

        return y;
    }

    // ascending sort function
    void sortAsc(Node *node) {
        //Add your code here
        //inorder
        if (node->left!=NULL)
           sortAsc(node->left);
        cout<<node->value<<" ";
        if (node->right!=NULL)
           sortAsc(node->right);

    }

    // descending sort function
    void sortDes(Node *node) {
        // Add your code here
        //inorder
        if (node->right!=NULL)
           sortDes(node->right);
        cout<<node->value<<" ";
        if (node->left!=NULL)
           sortDes(node->left);

    }

    void clear(BST *tree) {
        Node *n = NULL;

        while (tree->root != NULL) {
            n = remove(tree->root->value, tree);
            free(n);
        }
    }


    int main() {
        int A[] = {3, 5, 10, 4, 8, 9, 1, 4, 7, 6};

        Node *node = NULL;
        BST *tree = (BST *) malloc(sizeof(BST));
        tree->root = NULL;

        // build BST tree
        cout << "Input data:\n\t";
        for (int i=0; i<SIZE; i++) {
            cout << A[i] << " ";    // by the way, print it to the console
            insert(A[i], tree);     // You need to complete TASK 1, so that it can work
        }

        // sort values in ascending order
        cout << "\n\nAscending order:\n\t";
        sortAsc(tree->root);        // You need to complete TASK 2. Otherwise you see nothing in the console

        // sort values in descending order
        cout << "\n\nDescending order:\n\t";
        sortDes(tree->root);        // TASK 2 also!

        // Find minimum value
        if (tree->root != NULL)
            cout << "\n\nMin: " << min(tree->root)->value;

        // Find maximum value
        if (tree->root != NULL)
            cout << "\n\nMax: " << max(tree->root)->value;

        // delete 4
        cout << "\n\nDelete 4 and add 2";
        //free(remove(4, tree));    // You need to complete TASK 3, so that remove(int, BST *) function works properly
                                // we also need to release the resource!!!

        // insert 2
        insert(2, tree);        // It belongs to TASK 1 too.

        cout << "\n\nAscending order:\n\t";
        sortAsc(tree->root);        // TASK 2!!

        // Find the successor of 5, -1 means no successor
        node = search(5, tree->root);
        cout << "\n\nSearch of 5 is: " << (node != NULL?node->value:-1);


        // Find the successor of 5, -1 means no successor
        node = successor(5, tree->root);
        cout << "\n\nSuccessor of 5 is: " << (node != NULL?node->value:-1);

        // Find the predecessor of 5. -1 means no predecessor
        node = predecessor(5, tree->root);
        cout << "\n\nPredecessor of 5 is: " << (node != NULL?node->value:-1);

        cout << "\n\n";

        // clear all elements
        clear(tree);            // delete all nodes and release resource
        free(tree);             // delte the tree too
        system("Pause");
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well there is a bug in your recursive search for starters you need to have all paths return values like this:

```
Node *search(int key, Node *n) {
    if (n== NULL || key == n->value)
        return n;

    if (key < n->value)
        return search(key, n->left);
    else
        return search(key, n->right);
}
```

Apart from that I'm inclined to say try debugging your own code first and giving more details about what you've found rather than just posting code and asking what's wrong with it.  You're liable to get some real smart ass answers here otherwise ;)